# How can I get started with Android in Windows XP?

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I need to know how to install it in Windows XP. Which is the best IDE and what are its requirements? Also, how can I develop an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a beginner too, except I've been using [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) for java development for years. Starting Android development in eclipse was very easy, and the emulator installs, starts, runs, integrates well with eclipse -  it's a very professional experience.

Install the latest "java developers" package of eclipse.

The [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/index.html) website is where you should start reading, and following instructions for installing the SDK then the development tools to eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

You need the following

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads)
- [Android SDK for windows](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
- [Java](http://java.com) ( probably already installed :D )

You also need to install the Android ADT on Eclipse , here are the steps:

1. Click on “Help” in Eclipse
2. Click on “Install New Software”.
3. Click on “ADD” , Type in a name of your choice, I just use “Android ADT”. In the source    box provide the following URL “https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse”and click OK .
   Eclipse is going to query the address we provided and in a few moments it will provide us we a set of plugins, namely Android DDMS and Android Development Tools under Development Tools.
4. Select the parent, i.e., “Development Tools” and click “Next”.
5. Accept the Terms of service and continue.

You can follow the install procedure from the Android SDK page above or from a brief tutorial I wrote at [DroolJunkie](http://www.drooljunkie.com/code-uncode/beginning-android-development-together-week-1/)

Update : You may also use the following screen casts to help with installation ([Source/Credits](http://sites.google.com/site/iobootcamp/content/android))

- [Installing the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)
- [Linux](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4cz-szXk2k)
- [Windows](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuQiHMT8Qtg)
- [Mac](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMcJkdY2R60)

As for how to learn to develop on Android you can start by reading artilces and tutorials on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/) and using Stackoverflow and Google. There are also a few good books available. Here are 3 I like:

- [Professional Android 2 Application Development (Wrox Programmer to Programmer) by Reto Meier](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470565527)
- [Beginning Android 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430226293)
- [Books from commonsware](http://commonsware.com/) , The [Author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) is **Very** active on Stackoverflow :-)